# Twilio changing alphanumeric id to phone number

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-php

I recently started using Twilio to send SMS in one of my apps. Although the twilio's dashboard shows that the SMS was send using the set alphanumeric sender id. It arrives on my phone with a different number totally. Anyone have any idea why? There's nothing about this on the Twilio website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an issue that should be taken up with Twilio support.

Comment: @philnash True. However, it may serve as resource that will save developers a lot of time since nothing of this stated on the Twilio site.

Comment: Thanks for answering yourself then! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a carrier problem. They can change sender id (within reason) to increase the chance that an SMS is delivered. So there's basically nothing Twilio can do about it.

If you still have doubts, contact Twilio support.